# C - Sum of 1/n numbers

Tags: c, numbers, sum

Hello could you take a quick glance at my code and point out the mistake(s).
I'm trying to calculate sum of n numbers going like this: 1- 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 ... etc...

With the following code, I get 1.00000 each time, but it should be between 0 and 1, for example for 3 it should be 1 - 1/2 + 1/3 = 0,83333.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {

 int n, prefix;
 float sum;
 scanf("%d", &n);
 do {
   if (n%2==0) {
    prefix=-1;
   } else {
    prefix=1;
   }
   sum+=  prefix/n;
   n = n - 1;

 } while (n > 0);
 printf("%f", sum);

}
```

Comment: it's a typo.. doesn't work with prefix either

Comment: So what's the problem? Error messages? Wrong output? What's the output you get and what did you expect?

Comment: `n` has type `int` and `prefix` has type `int`, so `prefix/n` will have type `int` as well

Comment: I get 1.00000 each time, and it should be between 0 and 1, for example for 3 it should be 1 - 1/2 + 1/3 = 0,83333.

Comment: I'm not too much into c but could this be a problem that both parts of your sum+= prefix/n are integers? try changing them to float.

Comment: Thx, it worked, I added (float) in front of n

Comment: Do you really need to *test* the parity of every single element of a decrementing sequence of integers? One would think that once you know the parity of one element, you can predict the parity of the next one...

Comment: Also, check for divide by zero error

Comment: Others have covered the main issue, but also, you should initialize `sum` (as in Floris' answer). If you don't explicitly initialize an automatic variable, its value is indeterminate.

Comment: BTW:  You get a more accurate answer doing what you did, adding the small fractions to gather first, rather than other way around.

Comment: @chux - as written the code starts with the largest value of `n` - thus the smallest value of the `(1/n)` term. It would be fractionally more accurate if terms were summed in pairs - but I don't think that was the point of this question.

Comment: @Floris Summing the factional pairs - yes, good idea.  BTW: OP requested to "point out the mistakes".  When chess-masters compete, neither makes a _mistake_, but one's solution may be better, thus kudos for you suggestion - subtle as it is.

Comment: @chux - I just re-read your initial comment "You get a more accurate answer" - and realize it was a compliment, not a suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Three errors that I can see:

1. typo (`premix` vs `prefix`)
2. use of integer type
3. (thanks to @Light): initialization of `sum`

Try the following instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {

 int n, n_initial;
 double sum=0.0, prefix = 1.0;
 printf("enter the value for n:\n");
 scanf("%d", &n);

 if(n<1) {
   printf("n must be > 0!\n");
   return 1;
 }
 n_initial = n;
 if (n%2==0) prefix = -1.0; else prefix= 1.0;
 do {
   sum+= prefix/(double)n;
   prefix *= -1.0;
   n--;

 } while (n > 0);
 printf("The sum of the series over %d terms is: %lf\n", n_initial, sum);
 return 0;
}
```

Note - I keep `n` as an integer, and cast it explicitly before the divition. It might be better just to make it a float / double - remember to change the format specification for the `scanf` accordingly. I only do the modulo operation once (after that, the sign of `prefix` just keeps changing). Also - it's always a good idea to add a prompt for the input of a number ("why isn't it doing anything?!"), to annotate the result (rather than print "just a number"), and to end the output with a newline (so the prompt doesn't obscure the output of  the program).

Finally - you might want to check that the user doesn't enter a negative number, which would make your code give a bad result.

As an afterthought - you could test for large values of `n`, and just return `log(2.0)`. But that *would* be cheating... and this series does converge *awfully* slowly (it oscillates quite badly - the 3rd digit is still changing when n=1000). Consequently, rounding errors risk really compounding. This is why you need to be using the `double` type; but I would suggest it's instructive to look at other ways to compute `log(2.0)` - for example, using one of the other series given at http://www.math.com/tables/expansion/log.htm . You could actually implement all of them, and compare their accuracy after n terms (by printing out the error: `sum - log(2.0)`.)

Comment: No it doesn't - I change `prefix` sign each time. If it was odd in one iteration it will be even in the next. No need to repeat the comparison.

Comment: why not 'prefix = -prefix' instead of 'prefix *= -1.0' ?

Comment: @Karadur - no particular reason. I think the compiler will produce the same byte code. I don't like the unary operator much. Question of style/habit.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the above answers you have uninitialized **sum**(initialize it to **zero**).And I think your code doesn't  work when input is **0(it gives divide by zero error)**.So better use while or for loop or come up with an alternative in do while.

Comment: Good catch on the initialization of `sum`. Always better to be explicit about these things.

Answer (score 1):

you are doing `prefix/n` when both are integers. so you are getting the answer as integer (which always is 0)

use

```
(double)prefix/n
```

or

```
prefix/(double)n
```

or even

```
(double)prefix/(double)n
```

here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {

 int n, prefix;
 float sum = 0;
 scanf("%d", &n);
 do {
   if (n%2==0) {
    prefix=-1;
   } else {
    prefix=1;
   }
   sum+= (double)prefix/(double)n;
   n = n - 1;

 } while (n > 0);
 printf("%f", sum);

}
```

i ran it on compileonline.com with the input of 10 and got:

[image]

Comment: @P0W true as well. here, i wrote that

Comment: Online compiler usually initialize values to 0, if left uninitialized.
Use `float sum=0.0f;`

Comment: @P0W did it. anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Both `prefix` and `n` are integers, so that means you will have integer division which truncates the result (i.e. simply cuts of the decimals). If you want a floating point result, one or both of the variables also have to be a floating point variable.